# Laravel eloquent relation for nested select query of mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent, nested-select

I am stuck in the middle of nowhere in `Laravel Eloquent` relation for nested `select` query of `MySQL`. My query goes this way.

```
SELECT
  *,
  GROUP_CONCAT(p.facility) AS facility
FROM
  (SELECT
    `proposals`.*,
    `proposals`.`desc` AS `pending`,
    `proposals`.`Date` AS `date`,
    `pl`.`type` AS `facility`,
    `ps`.`id` AS `proposalStatusId`,
    `ps`.`status` AS `proposalStatus`
  FROM
    `proposals`
    INNER JOIN
      (SELECT
        *
      FROM
        (SELECT
          *
        FROM
          `proposal_status`
        ORDER BY `created_at` DESC) AS ps
      GROUP BY `ps`.`proposalId`
      HAVING ps.status BETWEEN 4.2
        AND 4.3) AS ps
      ON `proposals`.`id` = `ps`.`proposalId`
    INNER JOIN `proposal_long` AS `pl`
      ON `proposals`.`id` = `pl`.`proposalId`
  WHERE `proposals`.`desc` <> ''
  HAVING `proposals`.`status` = 1) AS p
```

This query works fine when I use in `DB::select()` and outputs the desired result. But doesn't work when eloquent relation is implemented which is as follow.

```
$proposals = Proposals::having('status', DMS::PUBLISH);

$proposalsStatusRaw = proposalStatus::orderBy('created_at', 'desc');

$proposalsStatus = DB::table(DB::raw('(' . $proposalsStatusRaw->toSql() . ') AS ps'))
    ->groupBy('ps.proposalId')
    ->havingRaw('ps.status between ' . DMS::STEP_5 . ' and ' . DMS::STEP_6);

$proposalsRaw = $proposals->select('proposals.*', 'proposals.desc as pending', 'proposals.Date as date', 'pl.type AS facility', 'ps.id AS proposalStatusId', 'ps.status AS proposalStatus')
    ->join(DB::raw('(' . $proposalsStatus->toSql() . ') AS ps'), function ($query) {
        $query->on('proposals.id', '=', 'ps.proposalId');
    })
    ->join('proposal_long AS pl', function ($query) {
        $query->on('proposals.id', '=', 'pl.proposalId');
    })
    ->where('proposals.desc', '<>', '');

$proposals = DB::table(DB::raw('(' . $proposalsRaw->toSql() . ') AS p'))
    ->select('p.*', DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(p.facility) AS facility'));
```

This relation outputs the same query as previously mentioned but results the null value. Please help me fix the error in this.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$proposalsStatusRaw = proposalStatus::orderBy('created_at', 'desc');` to `$proposalsStatusRaw = proposalStatus::all()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');`

Try to dump `$proposalStatusRaw` by adding this `dd($proposalStausRaw)` and let see if any result returns.

Comment: This returns error as the method all() doesn't support orderBy() . .

Comment: try using `sortByDesc('colunmName')`

Comment: Well $proposalStatusRaw works fine with eloquent relation . . I am facing error in $proposals . .

Comment: Where is the `$proposals` variable came from (in this line `$proposalsRaw = $proposals->select('proposals.*', 'pr`)? You declared `$proposals` at the bottom of your code. You should declare `$proposals` first, then use it.

Comment: Yea I had missed to mention the code there . . Thanks for reminding me . . Just added the code . . Now the top relation works fine for $proposals but the last relation doesn't work good . . Can you figure out why ?

Comment: Last relation means? `$proposals = DB::table(DB::raw('(' . $proposal........` this one?

Comment: Yes it is the one bugging me

Comment: Did you `dd($proposalsRaw)`? Did it returns correct values? Did it return array value or a collection?

Comment: Yea . . dd($proposalsRaw) outputs desired result of collection . .

Comment: What comes with `dd($proposals)`? Use this `dd()` at the bottom of your code.

Comment: It returns all the fields mentioned with null values

Comment: That means your `query` is fine. The problems in your `clues`. Try minimizing your sql clues, play with it, I hope you will find a solution.

Comment: I don't get you . . What do you mean by clues ?

Comment: `AS`, `GROUP_CONCAT`, `WHERE` etc. As an example, first try this `$proposals = DB::table(DB::raw('(' . $proposalsRaw->toSql() . ')'));`. see what comes with that. then add more clues one by one.